# C# console got error when delete file upon app exit

Tags: c#, file, console-application

I have a C# console app that create a file when begin and delete that file when exit.
In the first run, it's ok, but in the second run, it got an error like "cannot access file because it's used by other process" when delete.
This is my code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static string path => $"E:/abc.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
        };
        while (true) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file actually gets deleted after first run?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why not use memory, instead of creating and deleting a file?

Comment: @Felix yes, of course, I've checked that in file explorer

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have two apps A and B run on the same PC, A need to communicate with B so A write to a file and B just need to read that file

Comment: @NguyenHoaiNam so what if one tries to delete file before the other one has finished with it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest replacing that method of inter-process communication to another method - dot net provides several ways for inter-process communication - including message queues, REST APIs, named/anonymous pipes, Memory-mapped files and a few more I haven't mentioned here.

If it's a one-way communication on a single computer (one process only writes, the other only reads), the simplest way would probably be using [anonymous pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication). If it's a two-way communication, or it's over the network, you can use [named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) or [memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files#processes-views-and-managing-memory), or go with a more robust solution such as using a message queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced such problems for many times. It is because Create, Delete, Write and other methods of File class undergo performance drop. It has no legitimate solution. But, you can use a code pattern like below: (I hope it will help you out)

```
import System.Threading;

try {
    File.Delete(path);
} catch (Exception exc) {
    Threading.Sleep(500);

    try {
        File.Delete(path);
    } catch (Exception exc2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not share your personal contact details.

Comment: that must not be the case because I create file then delete after a while